# Why pmap shows a mapping that strace doesn't?

Tags: linux, mmap, virtual-memory, strace, pmap

I am investigating memory usage of a process that (unexpectedly) reserves terabytes of `VIRT`. If I do `pmap` for that process, I can see some beefy allocation, e.g.:

```
00007f39ea671000 317288696K rw---   [ anon ]
```

I am running my process under `strace` tracing all memory related syscalls and priting their stracktraces.

```
strace -o ~/strace.out -f -e trace=mremap,mmap,munmap,brk -k <command>
```

I would expect that I would be able to find this allocation in `strace.out`, so I grep it:

```
cat strace.out | grep -A10 7f39ea671000
```

and I only see this call to `mmap`:

```
106224 mmap(NULL, 201543680, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f39ea671000
 > /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.29.so(mmap64+0x22) [0xf5252]
 > /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.29.so(_IO_str_seekoff+0x2ff4) [0x84ab4]
 > /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.29.so(_IO_str_seekoff+0x3e0b) [0x858cb]
 > /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.29.so(__libc_malloc+0x22f) [0x869ff]
...
```

What is happening here? Does `pmap` shows exaggerated size of the mapping? Or do I miss some syscalls?

Comment: Is `pmap` able to tell a contiguous memory address range allocated in a single call from the same address range allocated via several back-to-back calls?

Comment: Good question @hidefromkgb and I don't know! I assumed that there is some coalescing of the memory regions going on but I haven't found any evidence for that.